# 3rd Normal Form Algorithm

Tags: database, algorithm, normalization

I will start with an example to get to my question.

Let's say we have the table Adress with the following attributes:

```
-Name(which also is the primary key, I will give this column the symbol N)
-Street(will have the symbol S)  
-City(will have the symbol C)  
-Region(will have the symbol R)  
-Zip_Code(will have the symbol Z)
```

The following relations are given between the attributes

```
N -> S,C,R,Z   
C -> R  
S,C,R -> Z  
Z -> C
```

I eliminate the states that are redundant with the following rule:
IF `A1 ...Ai ... An -> T` and there also is: `{A1...An}/Ai -> Ai` then `Ai` is redundant in the first relation.

Thus we have:

```
 N-> S,C  
 C -> R  
 S,C -> Z  
 Z -> C
```

Now, I must delete all the relationships `V -> B` where I already have `V -> A` and `A -> B`.

Which brings me to my question. In my point of view I have nothing to delete which means for FN3 I will have the 4 tables described by the relations above. However common sense tells me I should have just 2 tables mainly 
`R1(#name,street,city,zip)` `R2(city,region)`. Could I delete the following 2 relations :
 `S,C -> Z` and `Z -> C` ? (I have `N -> S,C` and `S,C -> Z` and `Z - > C` so in my opinion I go `N -> S,C -> Z -> C` which I already had so delete the former 2... )

Comment: 1. These are not "relations", they are *functional dependencies* involving attributes within a table. 2. Please quote or give a reference for the procedure that you (think you) are following. 3. You misunderstand it. Eg you are *not* supposed to make a table for every line you are left with.

Comment: I can't really find it on the internet. It's name in my country is AIDF and it determines the closure of A ... that's all i can give except pics in a language  you won't understand

Comment: 1. You can use your own language to give the steps you have used and how you applied them. 2. Can't find it? Via "closure normal form" or your title "3rd Normal Form Algorithm"?? PS:There is no English version of your text?

Comment: There is no english version. But i will translate it. Step 1 : Having A1..Ai...An -> Z if there is a relationship  A1.....An\Ai -> Ai then you can deduce rewrite the first one as so: A1....Ai-1 Ai+1 ... An -> Z. Eg: F -> N and F,N,P -> T then we write this as : F,P -> T . Step 2 : Group the relations with the same formula on the left side . Eg:  f1:N-> G, f2:N -> T, f3:H -> K becomes R1{f1,f2} R2{f3} .Step 3: Regroup the relationships: if you have X->Y and Y->X then put them in the same group. Eg: I have f4: G -> N. So R1{f1,f2} R2{f3} R3{f4} and applying the rule: R1{f1,f2,f4} R2{f3} . Finish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't delete those relations without losing information.  To take your example further, you would end up with `N -> C` which drops most of your attributes.

The problem is that you are treating all `->` relations as equal but they are not.  Maybe `N -> S,C,R,Z` is a 1:1 relation, but `C -> R` is a many:1 relation (many cities in one region) and `Z -> C` is a 1:many relation (one ZIP code has many cities).

Use different symbols to indicate these other relations, like `C =} R` and `Z {= C`.  Then normalize your table relations.

Comment: I see, i haven't thought of that to be honest. Thank you for your answer !

Comment: @LucianTarna This answer makes no sense. Eg functional dependency "Z->C" holding in a table means that a given Z attribute value appears always with just one C attribute value.